# アナコンダを用いたpythonライブラリインストール時に、特定の依存ライブラリのインストールをスキップしたい

Tags: python, conda

現在インストールしたいpythonライブラリがありまして、そのライブラリと同時にインストールされる依存ライブラリのうち特定のものをスキップしたいのですが、良い方法はありますでしょうか。

以下が依存ライブラリであるとします：

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

*bzip2              pkgs/main/osx-64::bzip2-1.0.6-h1de35cc_5

  curl               pkgs/main/osx-64::curl-7.64.1-ha441bb4_0

  expat              pkgs/main/osx-64::expat-2.2.6-h0a44026_0

  freetype           pkgs/main/osx-64::freetype-2.9.1-hb4e5f40_0

  future             pkgs/main/osx-64::future-0.17.1-py37_0

  **hdf4               pkgs/main/osx-64::hdf4-4.2.13-h39711bb_2 ←このインストールのみをスキップしたいです！**

  hdf5               pkgs/main/osx-64::hdf5-1.10.4-hfa1e0ec_0

  jpeg               pkgs/main/osx-64::jpeg-9b-he5867d9_2

  jsoncpp            pkgs/main/osx-64::jsoncpp-1.8.4-h04f5b5a_0

  krb5               pkgs/main/osx-64::krb5-1.16.1-hddcf347_7

  libcurl            pkgs/main/osx-64::libcurl-7.64.1-h051b688_0

  libgfortran        pkgs/main/osx-64::libgfortran-3.0.1-h93005f0_2

  libiconv           pkgs/main/osx-64::libiconv-1.15-hdd342a3_7

  libnetcdf          pkgs/main/osx-64::libnetcdf-4.6.1-hd5207e6_2*

これを行う方法はありますでしょうか。
ご存知の方ご回答頂けますと幸いです。

#### 追記

実際には、mayaviというライブラリの導入に伴うpyqtという依存ライブラリのインストールをスキップしたい、という前提でお伝えさせて頂きます。

依存ライブラリとしてインストールされる際、pyqt(5.9.6ver)がインストールされることになるのですが、mac環境下でこのpyqt=5.9.6はうまく動作しないことを確認しています。そしてcondaでインストールできる最新のpyqtは5.9.6であるため、私の環境ではpipコマンドでpyqt=5.10.1(こちらはmacでうまく動きます)をインストールした下で、mayaviを導入したいと考えております。このような導入を行おうとすると、condaとpipでライブラリの管理が異なるためか、pyqtが重複して2バージョン分インストールされてしまうことになるのですが、これによってpyqtを用いた処理がうまくいかなくなってしまうため、mayaviをインストールする際に伴われるpyqtの依存ライブラリとしてのインストールはスキップしたいと考えております。

Comment: こちら、なぜスキップなさりたいのでしょうか？（あるいは、スキップしたとして代わりにどうなさりたいのでしょうか？）　基本的に「依存ライブラリ」というのはそれが無いと大本のライブラリがビルドできないです。higa さんがどうしてこのような操作をしたくなったのかを伺いたいです。

Comment: nekketsuuさん　本文とは異なって、実際には、mayaviというライブラリの導入に伴うpyqtという依存ライブラリのインストールをスキップしたい、という前提でお伝えさせて頂きます。依存ライブラリとしてインストールされる際、pyqt(5.9.6ver)がインストールされることになるのですが、mac環境下でこのpyqt=5.9.6はうまく動作しないことを確認しています。そしてcondaでインストールできる最新のpyqtは5.9.6であるため、私の環境ではpipコマンドでpyqt=5.10.1(こちらはmacでうまく動きます)をインストールした下で、mayaviを導入したいと考えております。このような導入を行おうとすると、condaとpipでライブラリの管理が異なるためか、pyqtが重複して2バージョン分インストールされてしまうことになるのですが、これによってpyqtを用いた処理がうまくいかなくなってしまうため、mayaviをインストールする際に伴われるpyqtの依存ライブラリとしてのインストールはスキップしたいと考えております。分かりづらい説明になってしまい申し訳ありません。